# How to convert docker command to docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I wanted to convert docker run command to docker compose. Can you plz give some clue.

docker run -dit -h nginx --name=nginx --net=internal -p 8085:80 --restart=always -v /default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  nginx:latest

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Answer (score 1):

Use `docker run --help` to understand what each of the used options does. Then proceed to the [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) and find there how it is configured with `YAML`.

Note that some command line arguments have no equivalents in compose. That is either because they are not yet implemented or because they are also used as command line options. An example of the latter is `-d`, which run the container in detached mode. Its equivalent for `docker-compose` is also `-d` (e.g `docker-compose up -d`).

Comment: why voted negative here, i don't understand.

Comment: @SJS It wasn't I but I think that's because your question does not quite meet the [standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of a good one. At least it does not show any attempt to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: I am newbie in Docker container. It's request community to help if possible and encourage to cover extra mila. Thank you so much for help.. regards